# Django translation doesnt work in python code

Tags: django, internationalization

I have an application with the default language set to RU. My 2nd second language on the page is `en`. Everything in my `HTML` templates seem to be working except this part of code

If I set the translation to the code below. I will get only english translation, it means even if my page is in russian, i will get english translation of the text below anyway.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def get_country_info(country):
    country_info = {
        "Germany": _("Германия - это страна с богатой историей и культурой, расположенная в центре Европы. Она является домом для таких всемирно известных городов, как Берлин, Мюнхен, Гамбург и Кёльн. Германия славится своей архитектурой, музеями, пивом и колбасой."),
        "USA": _("США - это крупнейшая страна мира по площади и населению. Она расположена в Северной Америке и является ведущим мировым экономическим и культурным центром. США известны своими небоскрёбами, Голливудом, Диснейлендом и Ниагарским водопадом."),
        "UK": _("Соединённое Королевство - это островное государство, расположенное в Северной Атлантике. Оно включает в себя Англию, Шотландию, Уэльс и Северную Ирландию. Великобритания является родиной английского языка, парламента, Биг-Бена и королевы Елизаветы II."),
        "Turkey": _("Турция - это страна, расположенная на стыке Европы и Азии. Она известна своими пляжами, древними руинами, мечетями и базарами. Турция является популярным туристическим направлением для любителей истории, культуры и отдыха на пляже."),
        "France": _("Франция - это страна, расположенная в Западной Европе. Она является родиной Эйфелевой башни, Лувра, круассанов и лягушачьих лапок. Франция известна своей изысканной кухней, модой и искусством."),
        "Italy": _("Италия - это страна, расположенная в Южной Европе. Она является родиной Колизея, Римского форума, Пизанской башни и пиццы. Италия славится своей историей, культурой и кухней."),
        "Russia": _("Россия - это крупнейшая страна в мире по площади. Она расположена в Евразии и включает в себя множество природных и культурных достопримечательностей. Россия известна своей историей, культурой, балетом и водкой."),
        "Belarus": _("Беларусь - это страна, расположенная в Восточной Европе. Она является родиной Минска, Беловежской Пущи и Несвижского замка. Беларусь известна своей богатой историей и культурой."),
        "Uzbekistan": _("Узбекистан - это страна, расположенная в Центральной Азии. Она является родиной Самарканда, Бухары и Хивы. Узбекистан известен своей богатой историей и культурой."),
        "Kazakhstan": _("Казахстан - это страна, расположенная в Центральной Азии. Она является родиной Алма-Аты, Байкала и космодрома Байконур. Казахстан известен своей богатой природой и историей."),
        "Armenia": _("Армения - это страна, расположенная на Ближнем Востоке. Она является родиной Еревана, горы Арарат и армянского коньяка. Армения известна своей богатой историей и культурой."),
        "Azerbaijan": _("Азербайджан - это страна, расположенная на Кавказе. Она является родиной Баку, Гянджи и азербайджанского ковра. Азербайджан известен своей богатой историей и культурой."),
        "India": _("Индия - это страна, расположенная в Южной Азии. Она является родиной Дели, Тадж-Махала и йоги. Индия известна своей богатой историей, культурой и кухней."),
        "Thailand": _("Таиланд - это страна, расположенная в Юго-Восточной Азии. Она является родиной Бангкока, Пхукета и тайского массажа. Таиланд известен своей богатой культурой, природой и кухней."),
        "Japan": _("Япония - это страна, расположенная в Восточной Азии. Она является родиной Токио, Киото и суши. Япония известна своей современной культурой, технологией и кухней."),
        "South-Korea": _("Южная Корея - это страна, расположенная в Восточной Азии. Она является родиной Сеула, Пусана и корейской поп-музыки. Южная Корея известна своей современной культурой, технологией и кухней."),
        "China": _("Китай - это страна, расположенная в Восточной Азии. Она является родиной Пекина, Великой Китайской стены и китайской кухни. Китай известен своей богатой историей, культурой и экономикой."),
    }

    return country_info[country]
```

`settings.py`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "ru"

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('english')),
    ('ru', _('russian'))
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)

PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    None:(
        {'code':'en'},
        {'code':'ru'}
    ),
    'default':{
        'fallbacks':['en'],
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

UPD:
I am retrieving information via DRF

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def get_country_data(request,id):
    country_name = id 
    return Response({country_name : get_country_info(country_name)})
```